# does new Audio preload the sound file?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I get an audio element and play the sound like so:

```
let audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.key}"]`);
audio.play();
```

However sometimes (I use Chrome) there is initially a delay when I play a sound, so I also added this code:

```
let audioElems = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
audioElems.forEach(function (audio) {
    new Audio(`./sounds/${audio.dataset.key}.mp3`);
});
```

It seemed to make a difference at first but now again sometimes I get the delay. Does the extra code make a difference, will using `new Audio` actually preload the sound file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily preload it, but it creates an HTMLAudioElement with the `preload` attribute set to `auto`.
This means that UAs are told that they should preload the resource if they dim it appropriate, e.g, they could ignore it if on mobile data.

```js
console.log(new Audio)
```

Now to your issue, [Chrome is known](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162627) to not accept more than 6 simultaneous requests. So if your `audioElems` NodeList contains more than 6 elements, that would be the cause for some of them to be delayed until the first ones are fetched.

Also, there will always be at least a little delay, since all in MediaElement is asynchronous. Depending on what you are after, you may get better results using the Web Audio API.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 audio/video tags have an optional preload attribute. Is this attribute currently enabled on your audio tag?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_preload.asp

Using the `new Audio()` constructor defaults to `preload="auto"`, so that does make a difference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement