# Preload audio with <link rel="preload"> from Audio object (i.e. no audio tags in html)

Tags: audio, hyperlink, preload, head

In my `js` I have created one `Audio` object, with which I play/pause several audio files.
I was wondering if and how I could preload the files present in the `/audio` folder without inserting any  `<audio>` element in the HTML.

I tried `<link rel="preload" href="/audio/file.mp3" as="audio">` but Chrome gives me this warning:
"*`link rel=preload` must have a valid `as` value*".

I also tried putting `media` (instead of `audio`) in the `as` attribute. Same warning.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Say ... did you find how to fix this error?

Comment: The preload in this case is automatically set to auto. "This value is often ignored on mobile platforms." (MDN), but in my case is exactly what I wanted. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797249/does-new-audio-preload-the-sound-file
Eventually I removed the link tags from the head and the app is working just fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

You must add style using the "as" attribute like this:

```
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
```

This takes care of stylesheet in rel="stylesheet" which has been replaced by preload.